# How can I generate a print preview using Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, preview

Does Google Chrome have a Print Preview feature?  It doesn't seem to appear in the main menus.  If it does, how can I activate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no Print Preview in Google Chrome. You can find [discussions](http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=29ea05faa34bade4&hl=en) about this topic in [numerous](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6a0844c3207c5edb&hl=en) [threads](http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6895dccc1340303b&hl=en) on the Google support site.

The best way of getting any kind of print preview is to use a [virtual PDF printer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/), and just print what you want as a PDF. That way you don't waste any paper and you can see exactly how the printed document will look.

Comment: In .NET framework as from version 3, you also have included a xps printer that can print to xps documents. This is viewed in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the "IE Tab" extension ~ https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

and then use IE's "print preview" from within chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this now.

To force your page into print preview mode:

1. Press Command+Shift+P (Mac) or Control+Shift+P (Windows, Linux, Chrome OS) to open the Command Menu.
2. Select Emulate CSS print media type

[image]